# check if one hive table column value contain other column value

Tags: sql, hive

I have table A and table B. table A column id value is like abc-0924-0-3, table B column id value is like abc-0924, I want to check if table A column id value is contain table B columns id value for each row.

THX

Answer (score 0):

If the format is consistent (i.e. the first 8 characters of the ID in table A are equal to the ID in table B), then you could join using the first 8 characters:

```
select
   table_a.id as table_a_id,
   case when table_b.id is null then 'Missing' else 'Not missing' end as status
from table_a
left outer join table_b
on substr(table_a.id, 1, 8) = table_b.id
```